Sign-In with Ethereum and Account Abstraction
I'm struggling to understand how I might implement SIWE going forward in a world of Smart Wallet Accounts.
My understand with Sign-In with Ethereum for EOAs is to prepare a payload according to ABNF spec. then sign it and send it to my web server to verify the signature and extract the signing address, and map this identifier to a user account.
My understanding of SIWE with AA is sketchy:
I think the isValidSignature() method on the SCA must be called. But that means submitting a User Operation, which means generating the signature field. And that SCA may not exist, which invokes another set of hacky workarounds.
The signature may need to be wrapped in various ways, depending on the result of other checks. The verifier, which is presumably my web server code - there are never any diagrams or concrete realworld examples in EIPs - must inspect the signature bytes and make calls to Ethereum like eth_call to "a multicall contract" (which one? and what even is that?) before calling isValidSignature.
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6492
These EIPs are terribly written and there's something wrong with the review process if hundreds of documents of such poor quality are the foundation for this platform.
I'm lost. How on Earth does a web app sign someone in with an Ethereum SCA? Have I got to write all that stuff and who pays for deployment or to "make the contract ready to verify"?

I was having issues with setting up Sign In With Ethereum with Coinbase Smart Wallet using a Custom Backend for verification.
I may or may not be helping, but leaving this comment here may help you or others.
For the sake of simplicity, below is a basic example of how I got SIWE + Coinbase Smart Wallet signature verification setup in a Node.js API.
Setup your Environment
const { createPublicClient, http } = require('viem');
const { mainnet, base, baseGoerli } = require('viem/chains');
const { SiweMessage } = require('siwe');

// Map chain IDs to RPC URLs (use your own Infura or other provider URLs)
const CHAIN_ID_TO_RPC_URL = {
    1: 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID',
    8453: 'https://base-mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID',
    84532: 'https://base-sepolia.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
};

// Map chain IDs to Viem chain objects
const CHAIN_ID_TO_CHAIN = {
    1: mainnet,
    8453: base,
    84532: baseGoerli
};

Setup a Verify API Endpoint
app.post('/api/siwe/verify', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        if (!req.body.message || !req.body.signature) {
            return res.status(422).json({ success: false, message: 'Expected message and signature in body.' });
        }

        let message = new SiweMessage(req.body.message);
        const signature = req.body.signature;

        const rpcUrl = CHAIN_ID_TO_RPC_URL[message.chainId];
        const chain = CHAIN_ID_TO_CHAIN[message.chainId];
        if (!rpcUrl || !chain) {
            throw new Error(`Unsupported chain ID: ${message.chainId}`);
        }

        // Create a public client for the specific chain
        const publicClient = createPublicClient({
            chain: chain,
            transport: http(rpcUrl)
        });

        // Verify the message
        const isValid = await publicClient.verifyMessage({
            address: message.address,
            message: message.prepareMessage(),
            signature: signature,
        });

        if (isValid) {
            // Handle successful verification (e.g., create session, etc.)
            res.json({ success: true });
        } else {
            throw new Error('Signature verification failed');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: e.message });
    }
});

Full Example Node.js + Express.js App
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const { generateNonce, SiweMessage } = require('siwe');
const { createPublicClient, http } = require('viem');
const { mainnet, base, baseGoerli } = require('viem/chains');

const app = express();

// Middleware setup
app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({
    name: 'siwe-quickstart',
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || "siwe-quickstart-secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', sameSite: 'lax', maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
}));

// Chain configuration
const CHAIN_ID_TO_RPC_URL = {
    1: process.env.INFURA_MAINNET_URL,
    8453: process.env.INFURA_BASE_MAINNET_URL,
    84532: process.env.INFURA_BASE_SEPOLIA_URL
};

const CHAIN_ID_TO_CHAIN = {
    1: mainnet,
    8453: base,
    84532: baseGoerli
};

// Nonce generation endpoint
app.get('/api/siwe/nonce', (req, res) => {
    req.session.nonce = generateNonce();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.status(200).send(req.session.nonce);
});

// SIWE verification endpoint
app.post('/api/siwe/verify', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        if (!req.body.message || !req.body.signature) {
            return res.status(422).json({ success: false, message: 'Expected message and signature in body.' });
        }

        let message = new SiweMessage(req.body.message);
        const signature = req.body.signature;

        const rpcUrl = CHAIN_ID_TO_RPC_URL[message.chainId];
        const chain = CHAIN_ID_TO_CHAIN[message.chainId];
        if (!rpcUrl || !chain) {
            throw new Error(`Unsupported chain ID: ${message.chainId}`);
        }

        // Create a public client for the specific chain
        const publicClient = createPublicClient({
            chain: chain,
            transport: http(rpcUrl)
        });

        // Verify the message
        const isValid = await publicClient.verifyMessage({
            address: message.address,
            message: message.prepareMessage(),
            signature: signature,
        });

        if (isValid) {
            req.session.siwe = message;
            req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(message.expirationTime || Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60);
            req.session.save(() => res.json({ success: true }));
        } else {
            throw new Error('Signature verification failed');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        req.session.siwe = null;
        req.session.nonce = null;
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: e.message });
    }
});

// Session check endpoint
app.get('/api/siwe/session', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.siwe) {
        res.json({
            authenticated: true,
            address: req.session.siwe.address,
            chainId: req.session.siwe.chainId
        });
    } else {
        res.json({ authenticated: false });
    }
});

// Logout endpoint
app.post('/api/siwe/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error destroying session:', err);
            res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Internal Server Error' });
        } else {
            res.json({ success: true });
        }
    });
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


This will verify the signature, but it doesn't compare the nonce to the nonce generated on the backend, which is critical for SIWE. Otherwise, this endpoint is subject to replay attacks. Be sure to do so, like if (storedNonce !== siweMessage.nonce) { ... }

And be sure to invalidate the stored nonce on logout to prevent session duplication.
